# When saving to a model, created and modified aren't automatically populated by CakePHP. Using SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cakephp

Hi when saving to a model, my created and modified fields aren't automatically populated by CakePHP. It was automatically populated when I was using MySQL but now it isn't. I'm not using NOW() back when I was still using MySQL. Why is it? Also when a field's value is not set 'NULL' (with quotes) is inserted causing errors because SQL Server says I can't insert a string to a field of type smallint/date etc. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would set `NULL` as a keyword rather than quoting it, which I imagine is why your database thinks that it's a string.

Have you double checked the schema of the database to ensure that the `created` and `modified` fields are still `DATETIME` fields.

Also you say "SQL Server", and mention MySQL, so I assume that you are now using MSSQL?